# How nsswitch call sssd for credential?

Tags: debian, active-directory, kerberos, sssd, nsswitch

I'm stuck with Kerberos - sssd - AD. I've tried a lot of things, with lot of googling, in LinuxMint, Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 9. I have always the same result :

- `kinit username` works fine
- `msktutil -u --computer-name $(hostname) --server ad-server.univ-fr` looks good
- `ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI` works fine

but `getent passwd -s sss username` does nothing nor `id username`!

I tried with a very minimalistic Debian 9 distribution with `openssh-server`, `krb-5-user`, `msktutil`, `sssd` and configuration files `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` and `/etc/krb5.conf`. I did not change `/etc/nsswitch` as it seems to be right configuring with `compact sss` on passwd, group, shadow and gshadow.

It looks like that sss is never called. So I did not find any log that could help me to track the bug. I don't know if I miss a package or something else.

My question : How could I find out how `nsswitch` works and when it ask `sssd` to find a AD username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look into [Anatomy of SSSD user lookup](https://jhrozek.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/anatomy-of-sssd-user-lookup/) for an overview of the lookup process or [Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/users/troubleshooting.html) for how to get logs to see what might be wrong in the daemon.

For quick reference, you may need to add `debug_level=10` into all sections in the `sssd.conf` file, restart `sssd` and re-run your tasks. Then look into `/var/log/sssd*`.

Comment: Right, in this case additional debug logging and reviewing the logs seems to be recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did a very minimalistic configuration in `sssd.conf` file,as said in [Troubleshooting backend](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/users/troubleshooting/how-to-troubleshoot-backend.html), and sssd start correctly with good information in `/var/log/sssd/*`. Now I can continue.

Comment: Sometimes SSSD will not restart event if configuration files seem good and there is very little things in logs. This could be corrected by deleting the sssd pid file : `rm /var/run/sssd.pid`. This was my main problem/solution.